# Trouble Publishing C# Windows Form Application to Website

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, clickonce

I have been searching every post on SOF and googling up everything I can and have been unable to find anything that will walk me through posting my C# windows form app to my website.

I am using Visual Studio 2015.

I at first started to use ClickOnce but then, I believe, I figured out that ClickOnce only works with an intranet setup?
So then I decided to simply hit the "build -> publish 'application'" but that has not worked either.

I have found plenty of posts explaining how to "get the .exe file" but that is not what I am wanting.

While doing both ClickOnce and the simple publish application methods I managed to publish my files to my websites folders. I even can see the setup.exe file and application folder. However, whenever I put a link in my HTML code to the setup.exe to download it so the application can be installed it says "setup.exe File Not Found" and yet it is there.

I am able to download the VS application .exe and download it and run the app but that is not the same as being able to update it with ClickOnce- which would be preferred.

Is there any documentation that I may have missed that will help me, step-by-step, to publish my windows form application? Or does any know as to why it will not let me download the setup.exe?

-Colt

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.  One normally does not publish a desktop application to a web site.  If you want users to download your application, then all you need to do is copy it to the server and provide a link to it on your web site.  It's really that simple.

Comment: I want them to be able to "install" the application though. ClickOnce gives the option to update the application and can only do so via an installer not just the executable file. I am trying to publish the setup.exe file and have it install, on the users computer, the application that is on my hostgator website.

Comment: your installation folder URL doesn't appear to function, are you sure you are correctly listing the "Installation Folder URL"?

Comment: Are you trying to do this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @vipersassassin I may be messing up on that but I have tested my exact same html download link with images and it does work. So I am stumped.

Comment: @DD84 I am wanted to do something similar but my application is not a web application. It is a windows form application- If i read that correctlly. Thank you all for the help

Comment: @user3681591 I've done something similar.  You could zip the files for the users to download and the setup.exe file will point to the installation url and anytime you publish new versions it will prompt this user, if configured to do so.

Comment: @DD84 How would updating work with that method? Also, your advice is good but I am still mega curious as to why ClickOnce will not work or the normal publish method. I have been trying for hours and nothing. I am pretty sure my download link path is correct. When I try and download the setup.exe it says in m browers (at the bottom) "Setup.exe- No File Found" and yet it points directly to it. :/

Comment: @user3681591 - Linking to the setup.exe should work to allow the users to install the app, they just need to click "run" in IE/Edge (assuming this is a single .exe and doesn't require additional files).  Other browsers, however, require you to download the file first and then run it.  ClickOnce should also work, and is not just for intranets.  You do, however, need a certificate issued to you to make it work, IIRC.

Comment: @user3681591 the setup.exe file is pointing to the application files that accompany the application when you publish it.

Comment: I would love to figure out as to why ClickOnce is not working. Does anyone know a walkthrough of publishing my windows form application (not web application) to my website? I have scoured the web and have not found this step by step for windows forms. just web apps.

Answer (score 0):

I've used ClickOnce without a problem publishing applications from a website, so its definitely the solution pattern you are after. Documentation taking you step by step is here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4(v=vs.90).aspx

In general its the .application file that the user links to, not the setup.exe. Most browsers wouldn't let you execute an EXE file directly from a hyperlink so the .application file allows the browser to download the Setup.exe and locally execute it. ClickOnce even generates a boilerplate HTML page for you to install the application from - what happens when you navigate to it and try to install your application ?

Comment: I will try this. I have read that documentation and it does not explain, from what I have seen, what's the purpose and difference between the two publish locations in the ClickOnce Publish tab? The Publishing folder and installation folder. Does it matter where I place them? Thank you

Comment: If you search "ClickOnce Installation Folder URL" you get this helpful page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c37e68bc.aspx 

"... the location where users go to download and install the application is not necessarily the location where you initially publish the application. ... a developer might publish an application to a staging server, and then an administrator would move the application to a Web server.

In this case, you can use the Installation URL property to specify the Web server where users will go to download the application. "

Comment: So, the Installation Folder is the location the application will be installed from, and where it will look for updates from. The Publishing folder is where Visual Studio will write the files to. You can move them after you publish them as long as the user accesses them using the URL you specifify in the Installation Folder URL property.